# ¿Como vuelvo mi dialogo transparente?

Tags: c++, winapi

Quiero hacer que mi ventana, pueda volverse transparente pero quiero que una imagen(icono) que eh agregado se vea.
en pocas palabras ¿como logro que se transparente el dialogo pero se vea la imagen(icono)?flotando como una imagen

Aqui el codigo estoy usando el IDE visual studio 2019

```
#include<Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK Event(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hint, HINSTANCE hprev, LPSTR cmd, int show) {
    HWND VM = CreateDialog(hint, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, Event);
    //SetWindowPos(VM, NULL, 200, 100, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(MSG));
    ShowWindow(VM, show);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(VM, RGB(0, 0, 0), 0, LWA_COLORKEY | LWA_ALPHA);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK Event(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_DESTROY: 
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
```